# Siebel workflow search specification

Tags: workflow, siebel

I am trying to enter the value of the search specification input argument for Siebel EAI Adapter business service. I want to query for all the records from 'cross reference' which have Conflict ID value more than 0. I am writing its value as `([Conflict ID]<>0)` which is giving an error.

```
INPUT Arg: Search spec
Type: Expression
Value: ([Conflict ID]<>0)
```

Please suggest the correct way to enter this, as Conflict ID field is mapped to a system column.

Comment: Please consider 0 in place of 1

Comment: Have you tried without the (..)? And if this expression is used in a view which is based on the same entity? Does the expression work there? It is difficult to understand without more details. Is the error you see preceded by another error? Siebel has the habit of showing the final error message, but not the one that actually causes the issue.

Comment: Shouldn't the input argument be called `Search Specification`? Anyway, it would be helpful to know the exact error you're getting, and perhaps, the Siebel version which you're using.

Answer (score 0):

The searchspecs for EAI Siebel Adapter BS should be in the form IC.ICField. So if you want to check conflict id on Account ic, it should be ([Account.Conflict] <> 0). Try this variation according to your IO structure. You can always search in the flat tab of tools for examples.